# Plot received powers with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, frequency, spectrum

I'd like to plot the received powers over different wireless channels. For each channel, I have three values, and I want to plot them stacked.

Actually, this is my script:

```
set boxwidth 0.6 relative
set ylabel "dBm"
set xlabel "Channel"
set style fill solid
set key off
plot "RR1" using 1:2 with boxes, "RR2" using 1:2 with boxes, "RR3" using 1:2 with boxes
```

The problem is that since they are negative values (dBm), it plots from 0 to the value it finds, and thus the highest power is on the top. I'd like to plot a somewhat reverse image, with the blue box starting from the bottom up to the value it reaches, and the same for the other two values.

[image]

Any idea?

My data looks like this

```
21.0 -93.9207
22.0 -92.241
23.0 -93.452
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibity is to use the `boxxyerrorbars` plotting style:

```
reset
set ylabel "dBm"
set xlabel "Channel"
set style fill solid
set key off
set style data boxxyerrorbars

set xtics 1
set autoscale xfix
set offset 0.5,0.5,0,0

ylow = -100
plot for [i=3:1:-1] sprintf("RR%d", i) using 1:(0.5*($2+ylow)):(0.3):(0.5*($2-ylow)) lt i
```

Here, I used a fixed lower `y`-value, but you could also extract it from the data file with `stats` and do some other tweaking.

In the `using` statement, the second column gives the box center, which is the mean of actual `y`-value and the lower boundary, the third column is `x`-delta (half of the actual box width), and the fourth column is `y`-delta.

With some more data values, this gives:

[image]